# mTurk send_test_event_notification does not work for SQS transport

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

When I use Email as transport everything works perfectly. As soon as I choose SQS it fails, even if the queue itself works properly.
The code below rises the following error:

  `File "/Users/chapkovski/mynewotree/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/chapkovski/mynewotree/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the SendTestEventNotification operation (reached max retries: 4):`

**and here is the code:**

```
endpoint_url = 'https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
client = boto3.client('mturk',
                  endpoint_url=endpoint_url
                  )
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='whatever2')
response = client.send_test_event_notification(
Notification={
    'Destination': queue.url,
    'Transport': 'SQS',
    'Version': '2006-05-05',
    'EventTypes': [
        'Ping', 'AssignmentReturned'
    ]
},
TestEventType='AssignmentReturned'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is most likely because you didn't configure permissions inside your SQS queue. You need to add a permission to allow a Mechanical Turk system account to call the `sqs:SendMessage` action on your queue. [Follow the steps listed here on how to do so.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_NotificationReceptorAPI_SQSTransportArticle.html)

Once you do that, your permissions should look like this:
[image]

Then try the code again and you should get a 200 response.